# Scala Implicit function within a function call

Tags: scala, implicit

I've defined a class that has a method in it that is trying to make use of a function with an implicit parameter in it.  Unfortunately it's failing to compile

```
class Test {
    def useImplicit(implicit a: Boolean) = a
    def getAnswer() = if (useImplicit) println("yes") else println("no") 
}

object Preferences {
    implicit val yes = false
    implicit val no = false
}
```

The problem is that when I go to compile the class to try and test it out I get the error

```
could not find implicit value for parameter a: Boolean
   def getAnswer() = if (useImplicit) println("yes") else println("no")
```

I'm not exactly sure what is going on here. The reason for me trying it this way is I am ultimately wanting to overload hashCode and determine at runtime whether I should run my overloaded version or call the parent implementation.  If this isn't possible I suppose I could make the class take an implicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAnswer` is calling `useImplicit`, but there is no `implicit Boolean` within the scope of `Test`. `getAnswer` will also require the `implicit` parameter to work:

```
def getAnswer(implicit a: Boolean) = if(useImplicit) println("yes") else println("no")
```

The alternative is making `Test` require the `implicit` on instantiation, as you say.

Comment: The ultimate problem is I'm trying to override a function at runtime.  I can't add the parameter to the getAnswer method due to the fact that it would change the method signature and therefor not be executed by the calling code.  I just realized I need to use a trait and mix it in at run time when creating the object.